# How to get Cart Id in ajax-cart.js (prestashop module)

Tags: prestashop

I'm trying to retrieve the Cart Id inside Cart Module, ajax-cart.js in Prestashop 1.4.9.

I couldn't find any good way to do it as it is not stored in cookies.

Answer (score 3):

You have several ways to retrieve the Cart ID from the current visitor, the easiest one is to use the Context.

**Step 1: Open /modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js and look for**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Add below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: baseDir + 'modules/blockcart/ajax.php' + '?retrieve_cart_id=1',
    success: function(result_cart_id)
    {
        alert(result_cart_id);
        /* my_id_cart = parseInt(result_cart_id); Uncomment this line to store the value into a JS variable */
    }
});
```

Step 2: Create a file named ajax.php in /modules/blockcart/

with the following code inside

```
<?php

include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../init.php');

$context = Context::getContext();
if (Tools::getValue('retrieve_cart_id') == 1)
    echo isset($context->cookie->id_cart) ? (int)$context->cookie->id_cart : 0;
```

That's it!

Also you might want to consider the fact that by retrieving this value in Javascript it will be publicly known by the visitor. Depending on how secure is your code and payment modules, this could be an issue.

Comment: Indeed, it does the job, but it's cumbersome. Thanks anyway! Nice to find out it was answered by Prestashop founder :)